# How would I express the sentiment "Remind me again tomorrow"?

Tags: words

Consider the following conversation:

> **Miss A:** Mr B, could you please pick up the customer at the airport tomorrow?
>
> **Mr B:** Oh yes, could please remind me again tomorrow?

How would I in a natural way express Mr B's wish to be reminded again lest he forgets.

My first guess would be something along the lines of:

> Bさん：分かりました、明日も言ってくれますか？

However this doesn't convey the meaning of "reminding". Another way could be:

> Bさん：分かりました、明日また思い出させてくれませんか？

But I'm not sure you can use 「思い出す」 in this manner. Is there some better way of expressing the intent to "remind me again later"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'To remind' is one of the verbs that are difficult to directly translate into Japanese. 思い出させてくれませんか is grammatically and semantically correct, but sounds fairly unnatural to me.

明日も言ってくれますか is fine, but 明日もう一度言ってくれますか would be better. You may add 念のため, 忘れるといけないので or something to make it sound clearer and milder.

**EDIT:** Some businesspersons might say リマインドしてくれませんか, too, which may be safe depending on where you work at.

Comment: Yes it sounded unnatural to me too :) I guess I will have to resort to... uh how do I say 言い回し in English? lol.... Yeah I like the idea of using 念のため or 忘れるといけないので to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

> 忘れないように（明日もまた）言ってくれますか？